# Symbol not Found error on ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, awt, actionlistener

```
import javax.swing .*;    
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;    
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;   
import java.awt.*;    
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;   
import java.io.FileWriter;    
class Myclass extends JFrame  
{
    Myclass()
    {
    setLayout(null);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    //setBounds(50,50,700,700);
    JLabel lfname=new JLabel("Name ");
    JLabel llname=new JLabel("Lastname ");
    JLabel lmidname=new JLabel("Middlename ");
    JTextField tname=new JTextField(15);
    JTextField tmidname=new JTextField(15);
    JTextField tlastname=new JTextField(15);
    add(lfname);add(tname);
    add(lmidname);add(tmidname);
    add(llname);add(tlastname);
    JButton addrec=new JButton("Add Record");
    JButton delrec=new JButton("Delete Record");
    GridBagConstraints g=new GridBagConstraints();

    JPanel p=new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2,20,20));

    add(p);

    p.add(addrec);
    p.add(delrec);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    /*tname.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent oe)
            {
                System.out.println("Text="+tname.getText());
            }


});*/
    //tname.addActionListener(obj);
JButton save=new JButton("Save");
MyListener obj=new MyListener();
add(save);
save.addActionListener(obj);

    setVisible(true);



}


public static void main(String args[])
{
    new Myclass();


 }

class MyListener implements ActionListener
 {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent oe)
    {

            //if(ae.getSource().equals(calRect))
            if(oe.getSource().equals(save))
                {
                FileWriter fw=null;
                try{
                        fw=new FileWriter("c:\\users\\dell\\desktop\\File.txt");
                    }catch(Exception e){}

                }
    }

}
```

I am trying to add  Customised listener called Mylistener by implementing ActionListener on Mylistener class
I dont know what's wrong with this code but in actionPerformed() where the if condition starts is the location of error. Can anyone correct mycode?

```
Error is Layout.java:69: error: cannot find symbol
                                if(oe.getSource().equals(save))

                                                     ^
symbol:   variable save
location: class MyListener
1 error
```

Comment: If you're marking worked correctly

Comment: Accepting Answers : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Your save button is not defined in the listener class. You have to add it as a Parameter to your constructor:

```
class MyListener implements ActionListener {

  private JButton save;
  public MyListener(JButton save){
    this.save = save;
  }
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent oe) {

    // if(ae.getSource().equals(calRect))
    if (oe.getSource().equals(save)) {
      FileWriter fw = null;
      try {
        fw = new FileWriter("c:\\users\\dell\\desktop\\File.txt");
      } catch (Exception e) {}

    }
  }


//tname.addActionListener(obj);
JButton save=new JButton("Save");
MyListener obj=new MyListener();
add(save);
save.addActionListener(obj);
```

Comment: @user5681186 What is your problem?

Comment: I need to save the contents in a textfield to a file how is that possible?Is there any specific method to write contents to a file?

Comment: @user5681186 Look at FileOutputStream and Google for an example

Comment: Thanks a Lot @Jens :)

Comment: @Jens i have a program in which there is no constructor defined and is working perfectly without any error?It has Customised Listener similar to my program.so,why is constructor necessary here in my program?.

Comment: Can I post Code here?

Comment: @user5681186 No. Do you have a link?

Comment: @Jens No i have source file with me.

Comment: @user5681186 There you do not Need the constructor, because the button is a global variable in  the classs that contains the listener as a internal class

Comment: @user5681186 You are welcome. Please accept and/or upvote my answer

Comment: Accepting Answers : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work